# Error running simple copy task with grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

why cant I run this simple defined task with grunt? :

```
        copy: {
          templates: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: ['src/tpl'],
                src: ['**/*.tpl'],
                dest: 'dist/assets/tpl'
            }]
          }
        }
```

but when i try to run that task i get this warning:

```
$ grunt copy:templates
Running "copy:templates" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.templates exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "copy.templates" missing. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

is a very simple task, uglify and other tasks i had made works perfect.

Comment: Probably would be helpful to include the entire gruntfile.

Answer (score 2):

The `cwd` property of `files` should be an `string` not an Array.

Fixed task:

```
copy: {
  templates: {
    files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'src/tpl',
        src: ['**/*.tpl'],
        dest: 'dist/assets/tpl'
    }]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Foo>grunt copy
Running "copy:templates" (copy) task


Done, without errors.
```

Reference: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically